# What is the meaning of the following: " completion of open rounds of DNA replication"?

Tags: cell-biology

I am studying a paper about the relation between polyP granule and cell cycle exit. As the author explained the four general steps for cell cycle exit, the second step is" the completion of open rounds of DNA replication". But I really can't figure out the meaning of this sentence. I hope that someone can explain this to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the context of the [article I found from an internet search](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5373386/):

> Cell cycle exit in bacteria encompass four general steps:
>
> (i) inhibition of inappropriate reinitiation of DNA replication,
>
> (ii) **completion of open rounds of DNA replication**,
>
> (iii) segregation and compaction of daughter chromosomes, and
>
> (iv) septation.

I would assume that ‘open rounds’ means ‘DNA replication that has already been started’ (‘open’ signifying already started, and a ‘round’ has the sense of one event of a series). ‘Completion’ is obviously ‘finishing’, ‘ending’ — the cell cycle doesn’t end until all the replication that has started has finished.

I have not seen the adjective ‘open’ used in this way previously, and suspect it is uncommon, but as this is not my field I stand to be corrected.

Comment: Oh, I see. So, I may translate it into  the last round of DNA replication before entering the cell cycle exit?